# Index count using PHP for loops

Tags: php, for-loop

So i have this piece of PHP code,

```
$countRows = count($meta[text_group]);
for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][name]" value="'.$meta[text_group][$ind][text_name].'" />';    
    echo '<input type="text" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][value]" />'; 
}

$countRows = count($meta[textarea_group]);
for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][name]" value="'.$meta[textarea_group][$ind][textarea_name].'" />';    
    echo '<textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][value]" cols="30"></textarea>'; 
}
```

That produces this as HTML,

```
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[0][name]" value="Text Name 1" />
    <input type="text" name="my-item-option[0][value]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[1][name]" value="Text Name 2" />
    <input type="text" name="my-item-option[1][value]" />

    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[0][name]" value="Text Area Name 1" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[0][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[1][name]" value="Text Area Name 2" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[1][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Notice the name attribute in each input/textarea is allocated with an index number from the $ind variable e.g. my-item-option[0][name], my-item-option[0][value]. What im trying to achieve as HTML is the following...

```
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[0][name]" value="Text Name 1" />
    <input type="text" name="my-item-option[0][value]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[1][name]" value="Text Name 2" />
    <input type="text" name="my-item-option[1][value]" />

    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 1" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[3][name]" value="Text Area Name 2" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[3][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[4][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
    <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[4][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
```

So instead of the $ind variable resetting to 0, i want it to be continuous.

I hope i have made this clear.

Many thanks in advanced.

Matt

Answer (score 2):

Replace your second for loop to this:

```
for ($i = $ind; $i < ($countRows + $ind) ; $i ++ )
```

And use $i instead of $ind inside the loop

Comment: your anwser is very easy to follow :D @Andre thumb up

Comment: Hey, this is almost there however for the HTML on the second loop the $ind or index number are set as 2, any ideas?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
  <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
  <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
  <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>`

Comment: You have to use $i instead of $ind on second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my first crack was wrong :)  Going off what @Andre suggested I think you'll also want to change your 2nd loop to use $i as the index instead of $ind since $ind never increments.

```
$countRows = count($meta[text_group]);
    for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][name]" value="'.$meta[text_group][$ind][text_name].'" />';    
        echo '<input type="text" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][value]" />'; 
    }

    $countRows = count($meta[textarea_group]);
    for ($i = $ind; $i < ($countRows + $ind) ; $i ++ ) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$i.'][name]" value="'.$meta[textarea_group][$ind][textarea_name].'" />';    
        echo '<textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option['.$i.'][value]" cols="30"></textarea>'; 
    }
```

Comment: This won't work because $ind will already be equal to $countRows, so second loop will not be executed

Comment: Hey Robert, Unfortunately setting the $ind variable as your example doesn't work, i think this is because the $ind is set by the $countRows??

Answer (score 0):

If count($meta[textarea_group]) greater than count($meta[text_group]);
, you just have to omit the first initial value for second loop

```
$countRows = count($meta[text_group]);
for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][name]" value="'.$meta[text_group][$ind][text_name].'" />';    
    echo '<input type="text" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][value]" />'; 
}

$countRows = count($meta[textarea_group]);
for (; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][name]" value="'.$meta[textarea_group][$ind][textarea_name].'" />';    
    echo '<textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option['.$ind.'][value]" cols="30"></textarea>'; 
}
```

Comment: Hey, not sure whats wrong but the output produces the following  <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[0][name]" value="Text Name 1" />
 `<input type="text" name="my-item-option[0][value]" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[1][name]" value="Text Name 2" />
 <input type="text" name="my-item-option[1][value]" />
 <input type="hidden" name="my-item-option[2][name]" value="Text Area Name 3" />
 <textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option[2][value]" cols="30"></textarea>`

Comment: what the value of $meta[text_group] and $meta[textarea_group]?

Comment: $meta[text_group] and $meta[textarea_group] are both Arrays, so when i echo the $countRows for both they return a number. Hmm, maybe summing both $meta[text_group] and $meta[textarea_group] and use that as the $ind.. not sure

Comment: check the your arrays, because I don't know what exactly what you want to get @MattStrange

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything complicated with your loop indexes, it will only make your code more difficult to read. I would use the loop index exclusively for the loop and make another variable to hold the over-all-index.

```
$overallIndex = 0;

$countRows = count($meta[text_group]);
for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$overallIndex.'][name]" value="'.$meta[text_group][$ind][text_name].'" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="my-item-option['.$overallIndex.'][value]" />';
  $overallIndex++;
}

$countRows = count($meta[textarea_group]);
for ($ind = 0; $ind < $countRows; $ind ++ ) {
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="my-item-option['.$overallIndex.'][name]" value="'.$meta[textarea_group][$ind][textarea_name].'" />';    
  echo '<textarea rows="10" name="my-item-option['.$overallIndex.'][value]" cols="30"></textarea>'; 
  $overallIndex++;
}
```